# Jquery price slider filtering issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, range, price

I am using jquery price slider for sorting data based on price range. Now Iam doing this by following style,
1) while changing price range by slider, Min and Max values store in two textbox and after clicking find button result will show.

But, now I need to change this method. Now, I want to get result by changing slider range.(not by clicking find button).
  So, How can I catch mouse leaving values (Min and Max) from price range slider. This is my code,

```
$('.range-slider').jRange({
      from: 1000,
      to: 10000000,
      step: 1,
      scale: [1000,10000000],
      format: '%s',
      width: 180,
      showLabels: true,
      isRange : false,
      onstatechange:function(event, ui) {
         var range = $('.range-slider').val();
         var array = range.split(',');
         $("#min").val(array['0']);
         $("#max").val(array['1']);
      },
});
```

Comment: Please provide html of form as well.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to trigger your filtering code from within the `onstatechange` callback …?

Comment: Thanks for the support. I findout the issue behind this. In this price slider only 'onstatechange' is working, other events have no effect. So I changed price slider with JQuery Slider. Now everything is working fine.